# How to fix: Sass/CSS is compiling but not loading in browser elements

Tags: css, browser, sass, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a multi-page website with `HTML`, (`Bootstrap`) & `Sass` in Visual Studio Code.

But when I open the page with Live Server in either Chrome or Firefox, the elements do not adjust to my changes.

When I look into my Source Code in the Dev Tools, the changes are there though.

In Visual Studio Code I use Live Sass Compiler, and this also tells me successfully compiled... Side note: my OS is **Ubuntu**.

The only way right now to get my changes adjusted is by completely shutting down my VSC and my browser every time.

Hard Reload does not work either... this is really a hassle...

Does somebody what the problem is and how I can solve it?

Comment: you could try to disable cache in settings of your browser too

Comment: @elisek can you update your question with your configuration file ? https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-sass-compiler/blob/master/docs/faqs.md

Comment: It got solved eventually, the import files were compiling but my main.scss file was not compiling.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your css come into cache, try to versioning your inclusion: style.css?v=324423 (set a random value or a timestamp)

Comment: Do you mean in html? (like here: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css?v=324423">) That doesn't seem to work...

Comment: you need to variabilize that number on every page refresh